# Flask session: always getting new sessions on requests, request.cookies is always empty

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I am making a Flask web application, I try to use the session object in
Flask to store data ; in my `login` route I do something like this:

```
session["loginID"] = "the login id"
session["some_data"] = dict()
```

Doing a `print session` shows values are properly set.

My problem is the following: in another AJAX call, I try to retrieve
`some_data` dictionary from `session`, but `session` is empty.

I tried to find what happens looking in Flask source code, it turns out `request.cookies` is always empty for my requests, so `open_session`
returns a new session each time.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
def open_session(self, app, request):
    s = self.get_signing_serializer(app)
    if s is None:
        return None
    val = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)
    if not val:
        return self.session_class()
    max_age = total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime)
    try:
        data = s.loads(val, max_age=max_age)
        return self.session_class(data)
    except BadSignature:
        return self.session_class()
```

Does someone know what can cause this behaviour ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the cookie domain for ajax calls. I'm not sure why but I know it is important.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/

Comment: No it's not that. It turns out credentials have to be passed from web browser to server in the AJAX request, otherwise no session information is sent back to Flask ; so in my case the solution is to set `credentials` to `include` in `fetch()` call options. Thanks for your help anyway.